# dependency management with gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a following gradle build script

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'tests'
        }
    }
    main{
        java {srcDir 'web-schedule\\src'}
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile 'javax:javaee-api:6.0'
    compile 'javax:javaee-web-api:6.0'

    testRuntime 'org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.0.3.Final'
    testRuntime 'org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:1.0.3.Final'
    testRuntime 'org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1:1.0.0.CR3'
    testRuntime 'junit:junit:4.+'
    testRuntime 'org.jboss.weld:weld-api:1.1.Final'

}
```

i try to achieve fully automatic compile and test execution with gradle.
Basically problem is library dependencies. For compiling project itself without tests i need only follow libraries

```
compile 'javax:javaee-api:6.0'
compile 'javax:javaee-web-api:6.0'
```

but for test compiling i need also all the rest. But during test compiling process if i have it, it raise exception. I found the solution exclude it from test compiling and execution process. Now i doing it manually. What i want to achieve is do it fully automatically. What i need to do it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is it that you are doing manually now? Some of the `testRuntime` dependencies should probably use `testCompile` instead. Note that Gradle doesn't currently support Maven BOMs (as in `arquillian-bom`) - you'll have to list the dependencies separately.

Comment: the problem is that for compiling i need remove all dependencies except first two, then for test compiling and executing i need remove first two but leave all the rest. And i wont to do it manually, i just want to configure build script properly, and do it all in one click.

Comment: Thanks about BOM i will try to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you'd have to remove all dependencies except the first two for compiling the production code, as the `testRuntime` configuration isn't involved there. Not sure if you'll have to remove the first two dependencies for test compilation, but you'll certainly have to remove them for test execution. Here is what I would try:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        runtimeClasspath -= configurations.compile
        // additionally try this:
        // compileClasspath -= configurations.compile
    }
}
```

Comment: I need remove some of them each time because
`'org.jboss.weld:weld-api:1.1.Final'` and 
`'javax:javaee-api:6.0' 
'javax:javaee-web-api:6.0'`
is not compatible.

Comment: This doesn't explain why you have to remove anything for compiling the production code.

Comment: now i check some things and figure out that all dependencies not interfere each other for compiling, but do it for running. More precisely first two. But they need for compilation.
@peter I also check you suggestion and it is not working

Comment: I'd need more information to help (exact error message, stack trace, log output, Gradle version, etc.). First thing you should do is to check if compile dependencies are correctly removed from test runtime class path. E.g.: `task debug << { assert !sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.files.any { it.name.contains("javaee") }`

Comment: So, basically you were wright about compile classpath. I did following: `sourceSets {
    main{
        java {srcDir 'web-schedule\\src'}
    }

    test {
        java {srcDir 'tests'}
        runtimeClasspath -=configurations.compile
    }
}
` and it suddenly start work. I check the classpath and it become like i need it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

javaee-api-6.0.jar is a malformed jar, it has no method bodies, only signatures.So it's not possible to use it in runtime. So you can just exclude this particular library from your test's classpath:

```
configurations {
    testRuntime.exclude module: 'javaee-api'
}
```